# Set maximum AMQP client attempts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a case where I might have Java NPE into the listener which accepts queue payload. I get multiple attempts and errors:

```
 18:41:50.549 [processingeContainer-1] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
2019-09-24 18:41:50,551 INFO  [stdout] (processingContainer-1) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'transactionProcess' threw exception
```

Is there some way to limit the AMQP client attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You should really fix the NPE but you can configure the listener container error handler.

The default `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` treats certain exceptions as fatal.

It uses a `DefaultExceptionStrategy` which has the following code:

```
    private boolean isCauseFatal(Throwable cause) {
        return cause instanceof MessageConversionException // NOSONAR boolean complexity
                || cause instanceof org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentResolutionException
                || cause instanceof NoSuchMethodException
                || cause instanceof ClassCastException
                || isUserCauseFatal(cause);
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses can override this to add custom exceptions.
     * @param cause the cause
     * @return true if the cause is fatal.
     */
    protected boolean isUserCauseFatal(Throwable cause) {
        return false;
    }
```

So, configure your own `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` with a subclass of `DefaultExceptionStrategy` which overrides `isUserCauseFatal()` return true for `NullPointerException`.

You would then inject your error hander into the listener container or listener container factory.

Another technique would be to add a retry interceptor; by default, the error is just logged after the retries are exhausted. With spring boot, the default recoverer is a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer`.

**EDIT**

I just tested it and it worked fine...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So58087354Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58087354Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("here");
        throw new NullPointerException("Test");
    }

}
```

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=1000ms
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=2
```

and

```
here
here
2019-10-01 09:07:11.936  WARN 75435 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.r.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer  : Retries exhausted for message (Body:'[B@6d890bbc(byte[3])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=foo, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-mwYtmPtBplrefsOa05hG0w, consumerQueue=foo])

...

2019-10-01 09:07:11.937  WARN 75435 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

...

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: null
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT2**

To add a retry advice to the container factory manually...

```java
@Component
class ContainerRetryConfigurer {

    ContainerRetryConfigurer(AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
        factory.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(2)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 1.0, 1000)
                .build());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to add `retry interceptor`, please?

Comment: If you are using Boot, you just need to set some properties; see [Boot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Scroll down to the RabbitMQ properties `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=false` etc. If you want to capture the failed message in another queue, add a `RepublishMessageRecoverer` bean and Boot will wire it in.

Comment: I tried this: I added into application.properties these lines: `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=1000ms
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=2` but for some reason when I have NPE into the Listener I get infinite attempts. I can't find why.

Comment: I just tested it with your properties and it worked fine. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible that because I use Spring boot into Wildfly server this configuration is not applied? Application start method: https://pastebin.com/3cwmJQAm

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference as long as application.properties is on the class path. DEBUG logging might help.

Comment: in debug mode I get `2019-10-01 13:46:43,129 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) 13:46:43.129 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 82] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled] threw NamingException with message: spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled -- service jboss.naming.context.java."spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled". Returning null.` hmm. maybe I need to add queue name into the property? Advice?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Wildfly

Comment: Any idea why I get Returning null?

Comment: As I said, I am not familiar with Wildfly. Looks like some kind of JNDI issue.

Comment: For some reason configuration with application.properties is not working. Can you show me with Java code how to configure `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=2` please?

Comment: I tried this but it's not found during deployment: https://pastebin.com/j4gTzK3L I will try to run it as a standalone jar.

Comment: Gary I found something. Looks like I was mislead. This is the current implementation for listener that I want to implement: https://pastebin.com/Yd51jUgA  At line 180 I get: ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null` And queue is resend infinite times. Full log: https://pastebin.com/hatxXWqd So from this message I get many times ` Restarting Consumer`. Is there some way to limit this?

Comment: The retry interceptor is in the stack trace so it should no longer execute for ever. You are using stateful retry instead of stateless like me, but that should make no difference. I don't see any `RestartingConsumer` messages there. Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.retry` to follow the retry logic.

Comment: Can this be caused by missing or incorrect Spring-boot configuration? (I mean missing `RestartingConsumer` )

Comment: I don't believe so, no; but, as I said, I see no such messages in the log you posted.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I get `BlockingQueueConsumer - Rejecting messages (requeue=true)` when I get NPE: https://pastebin.com/Uk2QUUMv I will try this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: You've changed something else, there is no longer a retry interceptor in the stack trace. Why don't you try it with the application I provided?

Comment: I left only `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=1000ms spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=2` into application.properties file. I will try it with your code also. What do you think is this mean: `Rejecting messages` that `retry.max-attempts` is not reached?

Comment: I have no idea; `retry.max-attempts` does not appear in that log. At one point you clearly had a retry interceptor. It seems like you are changing too many things on each iteration.

Comment: I run the package with the messages consumer code as a Spring Boot application: https://pastebin.com/qE9FZAR2 And again those 3 properties for retry config are not applied. Definitely something into my package is wrong. Investigating......

Comment: Gary can you upload your project that you tested because I want to see what configuration did you used for the project?

Comment: It's exactly as I showed in my answer, but I have uploaded it [here](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so58087354).

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using `container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);`